# Array of different Confirm buttons jQuery UI

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

Is it possible to build an array of buttons and input this and it's code into a variable that I can use for different case scenarios with different code behind each button?  For example:

```
function showDialog(type, oEle, title, body)
{
    $("#confirms").children(':first').html(body);
    $("#confirms").attr('title', title).dialog({
        show: {effect: 'fadeIn', duration: 300},
        resizable: false,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "Yes": function() {
                oEle.remove();
                $(this).dialog("close");
            },
            "No": function() {
              $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

I would like to have different buttons for different situations, so I would like to call the showDialog function several times and use different buttons each time with this function, with different code executing for the buttons.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you mean something like

```
function showDialog(title, body, buttons) {
    $("#confirms").html(body).dialog({
        title: title,
        buttons: buttons
    })
}

jQuery(function () {
    $("#confirms").dialog({
        show: {
            effect: 'fadeIn',
            duration: 300
        },
        resizable: false,
        modal: true
    }).dialog('close');

    $('#one').click(function () {
        showDialog('remove one', 'some content', {
            "Yes": function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            },
            "No": function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        })
    })

    $('#two').click(function () {
        showDialog('remove two', 'some content 2', {
            "Delete": function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            },
            "Cancel": function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        })
    })
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/KUFR6/)

Comment: That's exactly it bro!  Thanks and Merry Christmas!

Answer (score 0):

Well what about defining buttons object outside the function? Like:

```
var btns={
      "Option 1": function(){/*show dialog 1*/},
      "Option 2": function(){/*do something else*/},
      "Option 3": function(){/*show dialog 3*/},
      "Option 4": function(){/*do something else*/},        
  }

function showDialog(type, oEle, title, body, btns)
{
    $("#confirms").children(':first').html(body);
    $("#confirms").attr('title', title).dialog({
        show: {effect: 'fadeIn', duration: 300},
        resizable: false,
        modal: true,
        buttons: btns
    });
}
```

EDIT:- Well as for switching dynamically, you can define `btns` object at higher level. Then pass an array of options that you want to show on each call:

```
var showButtons=["Option 1","Option 4"];

function showDialog(type, oEle, title, body, showButtons){
    $.each(showButtons, function(i, j){
        if(btns[j]){
            btn[j] = btns[j];
        }
    });

    //show dialog
}
```

As per `$(this)` is concerned, it will work. For other things like `oEle` parameter you can define some functions in such a way that you pass it into the clouser (well sorry for the sentence). As following:

```
btn['btnUsingoEle']=function(){
    oEle=...;//by the virtue of closure oEle will be available in 
             //dialog callbacks. 
}
```

Comment: But how do you limit the buttons object to only the buttons wanted in each separate instance? That's the bit I got stuck at.

Comment: What about the code in each function?  Should I be using `oEle` still and `$(this)`?  Will that still execute normally when it gets run within the function, even though it's being defined outside of the function.  Will that produce errors?